# Can't get my stack program to use pop

Tags: java, string, stack, java.util.scanner

So I'm trying to use pop() in my program and I'm not fully understanding why it won't run. Is it because i'm using a scanner? Can someone explain why my code tells me pop() in reverseStack cannot be applied to (java.util.Stack) pop(stack); ^ heres the code

```
import java.util.*;
public class reverseStack{

    Scanner scan;
    Stack <String>stack;
    public static void main(String [] args)
    {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner (System.in);
        System.out.println("Type something: ");
        Stack<String> stack = new Stack<String>();
        scan = new Scanner(scan.nextLine());
        while (scan.hasNext()){
            stack.push(scan.next());
        }
        System.out.println(stack);
        printStack(stack);  
        pop(stack);
    }


    private static void printStack(Stack<String>s){
        if(s.isEmpty())
            {
            System.out.println("true");
        }
        else {
        System.out.println("false");
             }
    }
    void pop(){
        while(!stack.empty()){
            System.out.println(stack.pop());
        }
    }
}
```

thanks guy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found multiple issues. You cannot call a non static method `pop` in `main`.

You may need to update `Stack<String> stack;` in the global variable to `static Stack<String> stack;` and initialize it in main and then call `pop` method which should be now declared `static`.

Or You could pass a parameter to `stack` to `pop` method and declare it `static`.

Answer (score 2):

The `pop` you're defining in `reverseStack` doesn't take any arguments. That's why you can't pass it `stack` as an argument.

Answer (score 0):

As stated, the answer to your main question is that you needed a parameter on the pop() method.  The attached should work.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Stack;

public class ReverseStack2 {

    public static void main(String [] args) {
        Stack stack = new Stack();
        Scanner scan = new Scanner (System.in);

        System.out.println("Type something: ");
        scan = new Scanner(scan.nextLine());
        while (scan.hasNext()){
            stack.push(scan.next());
        }
        System.out.println(stack);
        printStack(stack);  
        pop(stack);
    }
    private static void printStack(Stack s){
        if(s.isEmpty()) {
            System.out.println("true");
        } else {
            System.out.println("false");
        }
    }
    private static void pop(Stack s){
        while(!s.empty()){
            System.out.println(s.pop());
        }
    }
}
```